# FB.API for requesting profile picture not working on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

i am developing game with **Unity3D v5.3.1f1** and **Facebook SDK for Unity v7.2.0** for Android + iOS. There are leaderboard within the game that shows scores saved on Facebook, there are also profile picture on it.

code are implemented like this:

```
// Generate Graph API query for a user/friend's profile picture
public static string GetPictureQuery(string facebookID, int? width = null, int? height = null, string type = null, bool onlyURL = false)
{
    string query = string.Format("/{0}/picture", facebookID);
    string param = width != null ? "&width=" + width.ToString() : "";
    param += height != null ? "&height=" + height.ToString() : "";
    param += type != null ? "&type=" + type : "";
    if (onlyURL) param += "&redirect=false";
    if (param != "") query += ("?g" + param);
    return query;
}

string ids = "friend id here";
void loadFBProfilePicture()
{
     string query = GraphUtil.GetPictureQuery(ids, 100, 100, "normal");
     FB.API(query, HttpMethod.GET, dealWithProfPic);
}

void dealWithProfPic(IGraphResult result)
{
    Debug.Log("Callback called!");
    if (result.Error != null)
    {
        return;
    }
    profpic.sprite = Sprite.Create(result.Texture, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), new Vector2(0, 0));
}
```

Program just need to call `loadFBProfilePicture` function then the callback function `dealWithProfPic` will assign the texture to the sprite. This works perfectly on Android & Unity Editor, **but not for iOS!** 
After some debugging, the problem that i found is, the callback is never called. Log message "Callback called" never shows up on the debug window. 
Solution that have been tried is upgrading Facebook SDK for Unity to v7.3.0, but still no result.

*Additional info: tested on Ipad Air 2 with iOS 9.2*

**EDIT (25 Jan 2016):**
It is already confirmed by facebook that is a bug on this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1055166274505844/)

Comment: It must be a bug within Facebook's Unity3D SDK. I would suggest you file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ . Another thought, make sure you are signed in within the settings of iOS to Facebook as well as singed in to the facebook app?